# Authentication failing cf cassandra service broker (cassandra-cf-service-boshrelease)

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa, cassandra-2.2

I am using [ih-cassandra-service-broker](https://github.com/ippontech/ih-cassandra-service-broker) implementation of the open-source cloud foundry service broker API for deploying cassandra as a service in cloud foundry. But, the authentication to service-broker is failing.

The *security-context.xml* file contains the default credentials. I have used an online BCryptPasswordEncoder utility to encode my password and replace the password in this file. The authentication fails with the default as well as custom credentials.

Am I missing something? Would be great if someone with previous experience with deploying cassandra as a service in cloud foundry could give some insights on how to set service-broker credentials in cloud foundry.